# advanced bit manipulation - multiplexing bit in bit stream

Tags: bit-manipulation

i'm trying to perform some advanced bit manipulation. let's say i have bit stream of data, and i want to insert other bits every X bits.

for example, for bit stream of : 111111111 and bits: 00000
 with X=3, i'll get : 110110110110

using masks (in the example above- mask of 110000) and shifts will probably work, but also will be a nightmare.

thanks 
Itay

Comment: Do you really have to multiplex at that low a level? What about bytes, words or some sort of packet format? What is the application?

Comment: hi John. the application is pilot insertion in digital communication system

Comment: Damn. So I'm assuming you don't control the protocol?

Comment: you've got it right. as for me, i would have done it using FPGA or something in that area. but what can i do...

Comment: The best/easiest ways to do this completely depend on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer:

I would make different methods depending on X.

when X=2:

```
//Precalculate insertion bits
//Insertion bits must be not more than 32 bits in this implementation.

uint bits;//input
ulong ins=(ulong)bits;

ins=(ins<<16|ins)&0xffff0000ffff;
ins=(ins<<8|ins)&0xff00ff00ff00ff;
ins=(ins<<4|ins)&0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
ins=(ins<<2|ins)&0x3333333333333333;
ins=(ins<<1|ins)&0x5555555555555555;
ins<<=1;

//Packet streaming bits per 32 bits
ulong str;//input

str=(str<<16|str)&0xffff0000ffff;
str=(str<<8|str)&0xff00ff00ff00ff;
str=(str<<4|str)&0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
str=(str<<2|str)&0x3333333333333333;
str=(str<<1|str)&0x5555555555555555;

//Returns full 64 bits
return str|ins;
```

when X=3:

```
//Precalculate insertion bits
//Insertion bits must be not more than 21 bits in this implementation.

uint bits;//input
ulong ins=(ulong)bits;

ins=(ins<<32|ins)&0xffff00000000ffff;
ins=(ins<<16|ins)&0x00ff0000ff0000ff;
ins=(ins<< 8|ins)&0xf00f00f00f00f00f;
ins=(ins<< 4|ins)&0x30c30c30c30c30c3;
ins=(ins<< 2|ins)&0x1249249249249249;
ins<<=2;

//Packet streaming bits per 42 bits

ulong str;//input

str=(str&0xffffffff00000000)<<16|str&0x00000000ffffffff;
str=(str&0x00000000ffff0000)<< 8|str&0xffff00000000ffff;
str=(str&0xff0000ff0000ff00)<< 4|str&0x00ff0000ff0000ff;
str=(str&0x00f00f00f00f00f0)<< 2|str&0xf00f00f00f00f00f;
str=(str&0x030c30c30c30c30c)<< 1|str&0x30c30c30c30c30c3;

//Returns 63 bits
return str|ins;
```

and so on...
(I haven't tested this, but I hope you get the meaning.)

Comment: This might be to late... but for other people having the same problem :)